# How to set airflow task to up_for_retry on a custom exception

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I have the following python code running on a kubernetesPodOperator on Airflow.

```
class ExcecaoValores(Exception):
        pass
    
try:
    if condition <= 0:
            raise ExcecaoValores(f"exception")
    
except ExcecaoValores as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        break
    
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        break
```

What I'm trying to do is: When an exception is caught the task should go to up_for_retry state. Although when an exception is caught, the task gets marked as success. Why is this happening?